# ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_mod

Tags: angular, webpack

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false,"importLoaders":1}!./node_modules/postcss-loader?{"ident":"postcss"}!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
    at error (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
    at Function.browserslist.checkName (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
    at Function.select (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
    at E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at browserslist (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
    at Browsers.parse (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:44:14)
    at new Browsers (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\browsers.js:39:28)
    at loadPrefixes (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:56:18)
    at plugin (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:62:18)
    at LazyResult.run (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:274:20)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:189:32)
    at LazyResult.asyncTick (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:201:22)
    at processing.Promise.then._this2.processed (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:228:20)
    at LazyResult.async (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:225:27)
    at LazyResult.then (E:\MyWorkspace\Angular\angulartest\node_modules\postcss\lib\lazy-result.js:131:21)
 @ ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 4:14-127
 @ multi ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

Getting an issue with Angular on running > ng serve
Appreciate your help.

+-- bootstrap@4.0.0

Comment: See also: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/25118

Answer (score 3):

The issue solved.

I downgraded bootstrap with following steps:

1. Uninstall bootstrap@4.0.0:

   ```
   npm uninstall bootstrap --save
   ```
2. Then installed bootstrap@3.3.7 :

   ```
   npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save
   ```

Comment: we need to import that in your angular-cli?